# Xero Delete Connection

Tags: asp.net, xero-api, .net-4.8

I am using Xero in my application. I try to delete Xero Connection using dll in asp.net .net framework but unable to delete connection. how to delete connection in xero using .net framework

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65116349/713789

Comment: I am using this  await client.DeleteConnectionAsync(xeroToken, tenant);

Comment: I'm not clear with SDK you're using, but I would suggest using the officials SDK's.  For those SDK's we also have code samples which have examples of the full authorisation flow, including disconnecting connects/revoking tokens: https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-NetStandard#sample-applications